# How long will homemade Pico de Gallo last in the refrigerator?

Tags: storage-method, refrigerator, mexican-cuisine, salsa

I am trying to start doing more prep work in the beginning of the week due to a busy work schedule.  We love eating pico de gallo on omelets.  Was just curious how long homemade pico would last in the refrigerator.  Haven't made it homemade yet, but will be doing it shortly.  :)

Comment: My record is overnight because I whatever I don't eat when i make it, I end up eating the next morning. I think the tomatoes will be soggy and not nice to eat long before it's bad for you. 3 days for raw vegetables doesn't seem too long to keep it, especially if you have some acid in yours like lime juice.

Comment: Always try to store your pico de gallo in a container that will allow the juice to run off and seperate from the relish. The juice is what makes it get mushy quick. If you do not have a container that will do this than pour off the juice daily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I have mixed thoroughly I then put it in mason jars with lids and keep it in fridge for about 1 and 1/2 weeks. I have not found the tomatoes to get mushy at all. When I take a jar from fridge, I have to break seal as it does tend to seal when we put cap and seal back on. I hope this helps!

(In case it's relevant, mine contains tomatoes, red onion, lime juice, cilantro, jalapeños, peperoncini, salt, and pepper.)

Answer (score 8):

The Pico de Gallo I make (plum tomatoes, white onion, fresh jalapeno peppers, lime juice, a tiny bit of olive oil and chopped fresh cilantro, salt and pepper) will last approximately 1 week if kept in a sealed container in the refrigerator.  Over that time the tomatoes will get a little mushy and the cilantro will wilt.

Perhaps you can have everything else mixed and just add the chopped tomatos and freshly chopped cilantro when you are ready to serve?

Answer (score 0):

I've eaten pico that only I have made for up to 2 weeks.  I use a good bit of fresh lime juice and that seems to keep everything fresh for a long time.  As long as the tomatoes continue to look fresh it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Once you slice into a fresh tomato, you're looking at 1-2 days before it starts to get mushy and go "off" and 3 days to go sour (in the fridge). Fresh lemon and lime juice starts to go rancid after a few days as well. Best to make small batches fresh and consume the same day. 1-2 weeks? Oh, man...

Comment: I prefer the way my pico tastes after sitting overnight. So sameday is out for me.